# URL SEO : Using directories or exact keyword phrase in the URL

Tags: seo, url, keywords

I am trying to understand how to best optimise a url for a page to rank high for specific keywords. Example: a top keyword search is "rental properties in new york".

Question is does this keyword need to appear as this exact phrase in the url or should it be broken up into different directories for a better structure e.g.:

www.abc.com/en/properties/new-york/rental OR

www.abc.com/en/rental-properties-in-new-york

Which will help the page rank higher (given all other things on the page are exactly the same)?

Thanks!

Comment: Keywords in URLs are not so effective for SEO than you think. When creating URLs, think about users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about this too much, URL isn't that important. But, to answer your question:

If you use the directory URL, these should also work:

```
www.abc.com/en/properties/new-york/rental -> rental properties in NY  
www.abc.com/en/properties/new-york -> properties in NY
www.abc.com/en/properties -> properties
```

Also, you should have more options than just new york, otherwise this doesn't make any sense.

If this is a onetime page, you want the dashed URL.

Comment: There will definitely be multiple cities. So in that case you would suggest going with the /en/properties/new-york/rental ? 
Is there no importance of the user's exact search term being present in the URL?

Comment: Yes, the directory one, as long as you match the requirements in my `codeblock`. There is value in the url, just not really enough to care about. See it as 1% (<- an example!), it matters, but not much.

Comment: Cool.Thanks! Yes the requirements do match. Is there any difference in impact at all (maybe 0.1%?) on the sequence of keywords i.e. New York appearing before properties for example.

Comment: Again, don't waste time on this. If it's somewhat correct, leave it be.